# Intersection of sorted vectors

Tags: c++, openmp, simd

I know that intersection between two sorted vectors or sets can be performed using std::set_intersection(). Is it possible to perform the same set intersection using openMP 4.0 SIMD. I need to perform set intersection between two sorted vectors many times in my code, so c++ set_intersection() turns out to be a bottleneck here (as identified by perf tool). Is it possible to perform set_intersection using SIMD in order to speed up set intersection between large vectors. If yes, then how?

I am using gcc-4.9.2

I need to perform intersection between two sorted vectors -- where the first vector has size atmost 1,000 and the second vector has size atmost 10,000 elements.

If it is not possible to perform set_intersection using openMP 4.0 SIMD, then is it possible to do set intersection using Boost SIMD. If yes, then how.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Ugh sorry, I just noticed the SIMD requirement after submitting an answer for scalar logic. I'm not sure you can do it with SIMD given that kind of serial I/O nature, and because `std::set_intersection` is the one doing the grunt work. If there's any possibility to vectorize this, it's probably not going to be solved automatically by either OMP or Boost, but by using (or potentially creating) a `set_intersection` routine that's actually designed to be vectorized (not `std::set_intersection`). There either OMP or Boost SIMD or even writing the intrinsics yourself should work if it's possible.

Comment: Found this -- : https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/fast-intersection-sorted-lists-sse/

Comment: @lke Can you please share your scalar logic. Actually I want to compare the performance of scalar logic with SIMD. Actually after your comment, I too think that scalar logic should perform better than SIMD -- so lets try it practically

Comment: Are you interested in doing this with SSE (or AVX) ? If so then add the SSE tag and I'll see if I find time to put together a result using SSE and OpenMP. What type is this for (int32_t, int64_t, float, double, ...)?

Comment: @StegVerner Oh sorry for late reply, though `Z boson` has a nice answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some OpenMP code I put together to find the intersection of two sorted sets. It's possible to do this without a critical section when merging the results (as well as merge them sorted in parallel) but I did not do that here.

It's probably possible to do this with SIMD (efficiently) as well. I would do that explicitly using intrinsic or a SIMD vector class.

```
size_t intersect_scalar_omp(int *A, int *B, size_t s_a, size_t s_b, int *C) {
    size_t counter = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        size_t i_a = 0, i_b = 0;
        size_t aend = s_a, bend = s_b;
        size_t counter_private = 0;
        int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
        int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();   

        if (s_a > s_b) {
            i_a = ithread*s_a / nthreads;
            aend = (ithread + 1)*s_a / nthreads;            
        }
        else {
            i_b = ithread*s_b / nthreads;
            bend = (ithread + 1)*s_b / nthreads;
        }
        int *C_private = new int[aend > bend ? aend : bend];
        while (i_a < aend && i_b < bend) {
            if (A[i_a] < B[i_b]) {
                i_a++;
            }
            else if (B[i_b] < A[i_a]) {
                i_b++;
            }
            else {
                C_private[counter_private++] = A[i_a];
                i_a++; i_b++;
            }
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            memcpy(&C[counter], C_private, sizeof(int)*counter_private);
            counter += counter_private;
        }
        delete[] C_private;
    }
    std::sort(C, C + counter);
    return counter;
}
```